# Usage of that/and

Tags: word-usage

> The feeling you get when you re-discover a song from your teenage years **you had completely forgotten existed and actually liked.**

Should there be either an *and* or *that* just before *you*? Or are they  optional?

*It* is probably needed need in *forgotten it existed*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *that* is optional; but in writing, because of the interposed phrase *from your teenage years*, it would generally be clearer to include *that*. (You could do so in speech, but you could also indicate the structure of the sentence by your prosody).

*And* is not an alternative to *that*: if you use it, the structure is different, and you would need a resumptive pronoun: *and you had completely forgotten **it** existed*.

People do sometimes say such things without the pronoun, because we are making up our sentence structure as we go along, and sometimes come out with something inconsistent; but really it needs the *it*.

Further, I would say that (in all its forms) it needs *you* before "actually liked".